# How to invoke a Swift method with parameters from Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

If I have an Obj-C method like this:

```
- (void) methodWithParam: (NSString*) message
{}
```

Then I can invoke it with an argument like this:

```
[theObj performSelector:@selector(methodWithParam:) withObject:@"message"];
```

However if methodWithParam is an  method (or extension) of a swift class such as this:

```
extension UIApplication
{
    func methodWithParam(message: String)
    {}
```

Then there is an unrecognized selector exception when invoked via the same Objective-C code.

> [UIApplication methodWithParam:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

But, if the method does not have a parameter:

```
extension UIApplication
{
    func methodWithoutParam()
    {}
```

Then it can sucessfully be invoked from the Obj-C code like this:

```
[theObj performSelector:@selector(methodWithoutParam)];
```

So the question is how can this be extrapolated to include a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation process from Swift method name to Objective-C method name includes the Swift method's parameter name, following Cocoa conventions (i.e., adding "With").

The name in Objective-C of this method is therefore `methodWithParamWithMessage:`, so the `performSelector:` line would look like this:

```
[theObj performSelector:@selector(methodWithParamWithMessage:) withObject:@"message"];
```

Note that you can also just do this directly:

```
[theObj methodWithParamWithMessage:@"message"];
```

As MartinR pointed out, you can also specify the translated name explicitly if you would prefer:

```
@objc(methodWithParam:)
func methodWithParam(message: String)
{
    //...
```

Then you can do:

```
[theObj methodWithParam:@"message"];
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can override the Objective-C name with the `@objc(...)` attribute.